# Why Mac osx .App not running on prior MAC OSX 10.0 version

Tags: macos, jar, dmg, .app

I am facing problem of MAC OS App not opening prior 10.10 OSX version. My MAC machine have 10.13 OSX version and on this version MAC App running perfectly.
     In my App have only .Jar file and and Launcher file which is addressing to .Jar file. App open the .Jar file directly. This Jar file doing some system work also like create file and write system log.

```
 Please suggest to me solution for My App how to run on prior 10.10 OSX version.
```

Thank you

Comment: Could be lots of things.  What is the minimum macos version set to?

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply. 10.0 Mac osx version set to minimum.

Comment: OK and are there any messages in the console when you run your app on the "other" mac?

Comment: No. I am creating .App from .Jar file directly without using xcode.

Comment: I don't know, sorry.  You'll have to debug the app on that platform to find out where it's crashing.

Comment: Please try to open the macOS Console and then start your app on the system where the app crashes. Do you see any useful information in the Console app?

Comment: Hi, I will try to find out crash log and let you know. Thank you for your reply.